# How fix node-gyp forbidden errors?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, node-gyp

I have trying to build electron app with electron-builder but i have this error, how fix it?

i include pg on my project but electron-builder say need pg-native to build, and i have installed pg-native with ps2017 installed, now electron-builder showing this error

```
Error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe exited with code 1
Error output:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Unfinished Project\PBLauncher\PBLauncher Debug\node_modules\libpq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\AnonyX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v18.3.0/node-v18.3.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 403 https://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v18.3.0/node-v18.3.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: 403 response downloading https://atom.io/download/electron/v18.3.0/node-v18.3.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at go (C:\Unfinished Project\PBLauncher\PBLauncher Debug\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:153:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at async install (C:\Unfinished Project\PBLauncher\PBLauncher Debug\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:62:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Unfinished Project\\PBLauncher\\PBLauncher Debug\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Unfinished Project\PBLauncher\PBLauncher Debug\node_modules\libpq
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AnonyX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-25T08_38_05_586Z-debug-0.log
```

Compability

- WINDOWS10
- node@16.15.0
- npm@8.10.0
- node-gyp@9.0.0
- Python 3.10.4
- VS2017